# keychain storage is causing app to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain

I used `KeychainItemWrapper` for keychain storage.Everything is working fine when i use the `forkey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount`.But when i use `forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)]` app is crashing showing this message in console `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain Item.'`

```
- (IBAction)saveOne:(id)sender
{
    // save edits

    keychainItemWrapper1 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"one" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper1 setObject:[userOne text] forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

    keychainItemWrapper2 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"two" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper2 setObject:[userTwo text] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    keychainItemWrapper3 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"three" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper3 setObject:[userThree text] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
}


-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender{
    keychainItemWrapper1 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"one" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper1 resetKeychainItem];

    keychainItemWrapper2 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"two" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper2 resetKeychainItem];

    keychainItemWrapper3 = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"three" accessGroup:nil];
    [keychainItemWrapper3 resetKeychainItem];

}
```

can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look in your - `(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryToSecItemFormat:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryToConvert` method within your KeychainItemWrapper class.  Specifically look at your NSMutableDictionary that you are using to write to your keychain.  Have you set the key as kSecValueData for the dictionary that you use within the function SecItemAdd or SecItemUpdate?  If not, that may be where the problem lies.